# When does adapter notifyDataSetChanged finish updating the screen

Tags: android, baseadapter, notifydatasetchanged

I call myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() from my DownloadTask's onPostExecute. However the adapter's loop over the items is quite slow on older phones (because it has to unpack the downloaded files), and the screen remains white until all the item's views are ready. I would prefer to continue to show my progress dialog until the screen is "ready" with all the item's views. Is there a listener I could use to notice me when adapter finished the screen update?

Comment: so you. probably are doing some hard work in your adapter, dont do it

Comment: Unpack the downloaded files in the ASyncTask before onPostExecute gets called